# C# ASP.NET Core MVC JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued during server-side prerendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

My full error is

> JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued during server-side prerendering, because the page has not yet loaded in the browser.
> Prerendered components must wrap any JavaScript interop calls in conditional logic to ensure those interop calls are not attempted during prerendering.

How do I get past this error? I am using a ASP.NET Core app in Visual studio where my UI is calling an API method in another project to authenticate a user.

UI - Login/Index.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UserLogin", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "loginForm" }))
        {
            <div class="card">
                <div width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;>
                    <img src="~/img/shopkin.jpg" alt="" class="d-block ml-n3 mb-5" style="max-height: 310px; max-width: 100px;" />
                </div>
                <h4 class="card-header">Stacys Treat Boutique Customer Order System</h4>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Password, new { @type = "password", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="loginBtn" value="Login">
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

LoginController - / Controllers/LoginController.cs

```
 public IActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult UserLogin(User currentUser)
        {
            // Check the users credentials
            _authenticationService.Login(currentUser.Email, currentUser.Password);

            if (true == _authenticationService.User.IsVerified)
            {
                // Send the authenticated user to the Dashboard
                return View("~/Views/Dashboard/Index.cshtml");
            }
            else
            {
                // Show login error
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Service - Services/AuthenticationService.cs

```
public async Task Login(string username, string password)
        {
            User = await _httpService.Post<User>(_appSettings.AuthAPIURL + "/authenticate", new { username, password });
            await _localStorageService.SetItem("user", User);
        }
```

I get an error when the post is made in the service. I have not had this problem in previous versions of ASP.NET MVC apps before using Core

Comment: Can you please clarify what about guidance in the error message is not clear for you? (ideally by making an [edit] to the post)

Comment: I did not say the error was not clear.  I am not making a Javascript call at all. I am making a submission from the view to the controller which is calling a post to another Web API.  I am asking how do I correct this issue.

Comment: Which line does the error happen on? What is `_localStorageService`? You have not provided a [MCVE].

Comment: I stated the error occurs on the post statement in the service.  The code does not reach the localStorageService because of the exception.  If you want you can remove that line.  The methods are all complete..